# How can I install Lunar Lobster wallpapers in Xubuntu 23.04?

Tags: xubuntu, 23.04

Xubuntu 23.04 goes with blue wallpaper. How can I install Lunar Lobster wallpapers from Gnome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Xubuntu 23.04, you can use `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-lunar` to install all wallpapers included with Ubuntu 23.04 ("Lunar Lobster"). Or, you can download the package from https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/ubuntu-wallpapers-lunar. Once you have done that, you can change the wallpaper from the Settings Manager.